# How to get GeoJSON from Openlayers extent or extentinteraction?

Tags: openlayers

Currently I'm using the ExtentInteraction provided by Openlayers and I'm able to use the methods provided by extent to get coordinates. I can even get bottom right/left and top right/left, but I was curious if there's a way simply call a method and obtain the GeoJson output for the extentinteraction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the interaction's extent as a polygon feature in a GeoJSON string

```
var geojson = new ol.format.GeoJSON().writeFeatures([new ol.Feature(ol.geom.Polygon.fromExtent(interaction.getExtent()))]);
```

Comment: It should be noted that the method writeFeatures returns a string. There for you need to apply the writeFeaturesObject in order to have this return GeoJSON.